Struggling with mapping a nested Apollo query result to another value
I have a use case in Angular Apollo that looks something like:
eval(someId: number): Observable<string | Error> {
    return this.apollo.query<FirstQuery>({
        query: FirstDocument,
        variables: {id: someId}
    })
    .subscribe({
    next: ({data: result}) => {
        const firstObject = result.first
        this.apollo.query<SecondQuery({
            query: SecondDocument,
            variables: {id: firstObject.secondId}
        })
        .subscribe({
        next: ({data: result}) => {
            const secondObject = result.second;
            response = someFunction(firstObject, secondObject);
            return response;
        }, error: (error) => { return error }
    },
    error: error => { return error }
    })

In other words, I grab an object (returning error if the retrieval fails), then use a field of the returned object to grab a second object, then return a string based on some function of the first and second objects. What I'm not seeing is how to turn the result of the subscribe (which is of type Subscription) into the observable (string | error) that I want. What am I missing?

You could use rxjs's higher order map operator concatMap to transform the source observable
import { of, concatMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs';

this.apollo
    .query<FirstQuery>({
        query: FirstDocument,
        variables: {id: someId}
    })
    .pipe(
        concatMap(({data: result}) => {
            // concatMap will take value form first query and subscribe to the second query
           // and return the result of second query 
            const firstObject = result.first
            return this.apollo.query<SecondQuery({
                query: SecondDocument,
                variables: {id: firstObject.secondId}
            })
        }),
        map(({data: result}) => {
            // use map to transform the request
            const secondObject = result.second;
            response = someFunction(firstObject, secondObject);
            return response;
        }), 
        catchError((err) => {
            // common catchError for first and second query
            // and return an observable of it using of
            return of(err)
        })
    )

